# Variance in memory reported with perfmon vs Task Manager in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2016, performance-monitoring, perfmon

I am recording `Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use` with perfmon every 15 seconds but I see that it doesn't always tie to task manager's reported memory %. They almost always tie but when memory starts to climb on the server, perfmon will show much lower than task manager. Here is a recording of one example. Which is more accurate?

[image]

Comment: 56 GB in task manager is not the committed bytes.

Comment: I'm looking at the 89% in task manager vs 53.39% on the last line of the txt file.

Comment: Also not the same as committed bytes.

Comment: What is task manager representing then?

Comment: It includes the Windows "cached" and/or reserved memory, so the usage shown at Task Manager is usually higher than the "real" one (used exclusively by processes).